# How to make alert after adding a "wissel"

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

In my code you see there wil be an alert when you have 3 "wissels" but i want to have a alert when you try to add a 4th "wisse".

```
function addWisselTeam1(){
    aantalWisselsTeam1++;

    document.getElementById("aantalWisselsTeam1").innerHTML = aantalWisselsTeam1;    

    if(aantalWisselsTeam1 >= 3){
        alert("U heeft nu 3 wissels gebruikt");

        aantalWisselsTeam1--;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like a typo, unless you really didn't know that `>=` isn't the same as `>`....

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the greater count ([comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)).

```
if (aantalWisselsTeam1 > 3) {
//                     ^
```

Beside that, I would move the check to top of the function to avond incrementing and decrementing and exit if the number is greater than three.

```
function addWisselTeam1() {
    if (aantalWisselsTeam1 > 3) {               // check first
        alert("U heeft nu 3 wissels gebruikt");
        return;                                 // exit early
    }
    aantalWisselsTeam1++;
    document.getElementById("aantalWisselsTeam1").innerHTML = aantalWisselsTeam1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addWisselTeam1(){
aantalWisselsTeam1++;

document.getElementById("aantalWisselsTeam1").innerHTML = aantalWisselsTeam1;    

if(aantalWisselsTeam1 > 3){
    alert("U heeft nu 3 wissels gebruikt");

    aantalWisselsTeam1--;
}
```